# How can I return two different strings based on try/finally blocks using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, redux

I am trying to return two different states based on the timer set on setTimeout in try/finally blocks but once I return the state in the try block, the finally block does not return anything. Is there a way to get around this? I am trying to pass a string value that will be a notification then 5 seconds later return an empty string so the notification can clear...

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const notificationSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'notification',
  initialState: '',
  reducers: {
    createNotification: {
      reducer(state, action) {
        try {
          state = `You voted for ${action.payload[0]}`
        } finally {
          setTimeout(() => {
            state = ' '
          }, 5000);
        }
        return state
      },
      prepare(...args) {
        return {
          payload: args
        }
      }
    }
}})

export const { createNotification } = notificationSlice.actions
export default notificationSlice.reducer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `setTimeout` is async, the `return state` actually gets run before the setTimeout callback runs.
So your state gets returned first, then when the callback runs, it will do nothing.
I don't think the `try...finally` will make any difference here.
You would have to implement another `reduces` method, for closing the notification, and run that with a `setTimeout`.
(sorry not sure how that would look here, but that's what I had to do when I worked with react reducers)

Answer (score 0):

You can return an object instead of a string.

```
try {
    state.foo = `You voted for ${action.payload[0]}`
} finally {
    setTimeout(() => {
        state.foo = ''
    }, 1000);
}
return state
```